# How to resize web view when keyboard appears on iOS (Cordova)

Tags: ios, cordova

On Phonegap 3.7.0, when the keyboard appears on iPhone or iPad, the web view is not resized, and the keyboard ends up above the footer. I would like the web view to be shrunk so that the footer would remain visible. Is there anyway to fix this?

I've seen a lot of questions here to actually achieve the opposite, but that was with previous versions of Cordova/Phonegap.

FYI, I tried the following: resize the body when the keyboard appears (I use the Ionic keyboard plugin to know when it is shown and it's height) and change the `bottom` value of my footer. This does work on iPhone 6.1.3, but not on iPhone/iPad 8.*. Even if the body is smaller, the body is still scrollable, as if it still was 100%. I tried removing my meta tag content with `width=device-width`, but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One option is to use a plugin to shrink the native WebView. Add `cordova-plugin-keyboard` to you project:

```
phonegap plugin add cordova-plugin-keyboard
```

then in your config.xml add

```
<preference name="KeyboardShrinksView" value="true" />
```

or call this method in your javascript

```
Keyboard.shrinkView(true);
```