# keyboard events and resizing Cordova webview when keyboard is shown

Tags: android, ios, cordova, keyboard

I have an application that needs to have two separate behaviours when the keyboard is shown:

- Certain controls need to be hidden, for which purpose a keyboard show/hide event is required (a requirement discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20081949/detecting-android-softkeyboard-show-hide-events), among others).
- I need the web view to resize so that controls which are aligned with the bottom of the view remain visible (a requirement discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31179470/how-to-resize-web-view-when-keyboard-appears-on-ios-cordova)).

The common suggestion for the former is to use the `ionic-plugin-keyboard` plugin (despite this not being an ionic app), which provides events `native.keyboardshow` and `native.keyboardhide` that work in both iOS and Android for this purpose.

The common suggestion for the latter is to use the `cordova-plugin-keyboard` plugin, which provides both a preference that can be configured using `config.xml` and a method that controls the setting at runtime.  While this plugin also includes events for detecting keyboard changes, these events are apparently only available under iOS, but I need my application to run on both iOS and Android.

Unfortunately, these two plugins are not compatible: both define the same javascript interface object (`cordova.plugins.Keyboard`), so only one can exist in a project at any time.

How can I get both of these behaviours working at the same time?